# ngAnimate on ngShow in ngRouted templateURL. Preventing animation when it starts first time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-animation

I am using [ng-show #animation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow#animations).

index.html: -

```
<body>
 <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

templateURL contains:-

```
<button ng-init='shw=false', ng-click='shw=!shw;', class='share'> press me </button> 
<div ng-init='shw=false', ng-show='shw', class='animate-show'>

<h1> this is animation showing </h1>
<h2> even in the begining which it should not </h2>

</div>
```

In the above code the templateURL file should not show or slide up when page loads.

Please view the following two plunkrs.

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/ScdQXfD4OFuePvBT9ey4?p=preview) is expected behavior

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/PM0YZj2MQmw2ktvf88lc?p=preview) is the behavior we get when using ngAnimate and ngRoute together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ng-if in place of ng-show to get your desired animation.

You can checkout this plunker I created using your sample code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzxrwzecaX2yrEcSwvEn?p=preview